# Passing Variable in html extension pages. like html?a=asdfadf

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, parameter-passing

I want to pass variable in .html extension pages and .html pages are made up of mod rewrite so these are not html files but php script which are made .html through mod rewrite.
any clue?

EDIT:  My .htaccess file*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^watch/(.*)/(.*).html$ video.php?tag=$1&video=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+).html$ index.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html?([a-zA-Z=]+)$ index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

* As supplied in the comments.  Spacing may be different than the original.

Comment: What does your .htaccess look like?

Comment: I;m sorry if i could not tell in detail. I've successfully created .htaccess and works fine. but after that i still need a variable like .html?orderby=views

Comment: RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^watch/(.*)/(.*).html$ video.php?tag=$1&video=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+).html$ index.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*).html?([a-zA-Z=]+)$ index.php?tag=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`[QSA]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) to your rewrites.  That will take the original query string and add your new params to it.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite `whatever.html?orderby=views` into `index.php?tag=whatever&orderby=views`.

The only catch is, with PHP anyway, `whatever.html?tag=somethingelse` will give you some weirdness.  (`$_GET['tag']` will have two values, but only the one that shows up last will be the real value.)  But that's generally fine; you just have to be sure not to provide URLs like that, and you can just not care what people trying those wacky URLs see.  (Assuming, of course, that you validate `$_GET['tag']` properly.)

Comment: @WordpressGuru: Not a problem.  If this helped, click the little checkbox next to the answer.  :)